# Odd script behavior copying files on RPi 3

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Writing a script to keep on a flash drive, used for updating code on multiple raspberry Pis.  The idea is, I backup the directory from the raspberry pi sd card, to the flash drive, then copy the new files to from the flash drive to the sd card in the pi.

The behavior I get is that everything is moved from the flash, to the SD cards /home/pi/ directory, nothing is moved to the Flash drive.

I've tried using the shutil.move with the copy and copy2 parameter, i've tried just copy or copy2.

```py
#backupDir = /media/pi/mountpoint/SimulatorBackup which is where it should be
backupDir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'SimulatorBackup')
#flashDir = /media/pi/mountpoint/Simulator which is correct
flashDir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'Simulator')
#homeDir = /home/pi/Simulator which is correct
homeDir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Simulator')

def copyAllFilesinDir(srcDir, dstDir):
    # Check if both the are directories
    if os.path.isdir(srcDir) and os.path.isdir(dstDir) :
        # Iterate over all the files in source directory
        print("Copying from ",srcDir, "to ", dstDir)
        #this returns Copying from /home/pi/Simulator to /media/pi/mountpoint/SimulatorBackup on first run
        #Copying from /media/pi/mountpoint/Simulator to /home/pi/Simulator on second run
        for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '*'):
            print(filePath)
            #this returns /home/pi/Simulator
        #for file in srcDir    # Move each file to destination Directory
            shutil.move(filePath, dstDir, shutil.copy);
    else:
        print("srcDir & dstDir should be Directories")

#check for the backup directory before deleting it and remaking
if os.path.isdir(backupDir):
    #empty current backup directory and remake
    shutil.rmtree(backupDir)
    os.makedirs(backupDir)
else:
    os.makedirs(backupDir)

#copy files to backup directory on flash drive
copyAllFilesinDir(homeDir,backupDir)

#move new files to Simulator directory on raspberry pi
if not os.path.isdir(homeDir):
    os.makedirs(homeDir)
copyAllFilesinDir(flashDir,homeDir)
```

No errors.  I end up with /home/pi/Simulator/Simulator and /home/pi/Simulator/SimulatorBackup both populated, and no directories on the flash drive.
I expect the flash drive to contain /Simulator/ and /SimulatorBackup in its root directory, and /home/pi/Simulator to have the new files from the flash drive /Simulator/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I backup the directory from the raspberry pi sd card, to the flash drive, then copy the new files to from the flash drive to the sd card in the pi.

You seem to confuse *copy* with *move* - the `shutil.move(filePath, dstDir, shutil.copy)` *moves* files *from the flash drive to the sd card* (i. e. they are removed from the flash drive), namely, because of the `for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '*')`, all files with names *beginning* with `/media/pi/mountpoint/Simulator`, which of course includes `/media/pi/mountpoint/SimulatorBackup`. Perhaps you meant `for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '/*')` instead.

> The behavior I get is that everything is moved from the flash, to the SD cards /home/pi/ directory, nothing is moved to the Flash drive.

It's not true that *nothing is moved to the Flash drive* - it's just that `…/Simulator*` is moved back in the second step.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I did get my problem sorted out, but I did it via a completely different route. I was under the impression that shutil.move(filePath, dstDir, shutil.copy) would indeed do a copy instead of a move (with the third parameter).  Thanks for pointing out the '/*' vs the '*' difference, that explains that problem.